# Missing Namespace in ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am just trying to learn about creating web applications using ASP.NET MVC and I'm following some tutorial I have found online, but they are not giving any answers and I'm not sure why I am getting an error as I am following it.

The error I get is:

> The type or namespace (Genre) could not be found.

I have created a SQL database and also 2 models and a controller, no view so far as it isn't required. The models are named `ForestContext` and the other is named `Music`.

`Music` will be where the database is linked to.

If I open up the music class, there is namespace genre defined as a string.

The code I am using to display the genres of music is;

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IList<Genre> genrelist = _context.Genre.ToList();
    return View(genrelist);
}
```

I am not sure why it doesn't recognize that I am using the namespace `Genre`. It also states the error of not recognizing _context but I assume this is from the same class (`Music`).

I have also added;

```
using MyFirstForest.Models
```

As before this, I was asked to create an object of the `ForestContext` class, done so as;

```
private ForestContext context;

public HomeController()
{
    context = new ForestContext();
}
```

And that wouldn't work unless I added using `MyFirstForest.Models`.

Please let me know if I need to post any more information but this is all I have got to so far.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Regards,
DC

Comment: You have to specify the namespace `MyFirstForest.Models` because there could be more than one class with the same name in different namespaces.

Comment: @derloopkat thanks for the response, I have tried multiple methods but none seem to work. Can you elaborate your answer for me?